# Why does SourceSafe 2005 seem to show all Project Folders as being different?

Tags: source-control

From within Visual SourceSafe 2005 I'm selecting 
**Show Differences** 
**Show files that are different in both locations** and **Recursive**

There are no differences between the files in SourceSafe and the files in Working Directory however . . .

After Visual SourceSafe 2005 completes the comparison the (Project Difference) dialog shows every (Folder) in the project, to me, suggesting there are many differences.

Does anyone know why Visual SourceSafe 2005 lists all project folders in Project Differences even though there are no differences?

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TwxP.png)